# MAXDOP with Database Scoped Configuration on SQL 2016

Tags: 2016, sql-server

It's a requirement to install SharePoint 2016 with a SQL Server that has MAXDOP=1. It's long been a best practice to configure SharePoint with its own SQL instance, and this is certainly one reason why. However, SQL 2016 can now set MAXDOP at the database level via Database Scoped Configuration.

Is it possible to install/configure SharePoint 2016 on an instance where MAXDOP!=1, but with MAXDOP=1 at the database level? (perhaps switch maxdop to 1, install SP, and then change maxdop to 0 at the instance level and 1 at the database level for SP databases?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint will still require the instance level configuration of MAXDOP = 1 and will even set it at the instance level during the install process if you have the sysadmin role.

Comment: I think it only requires it when new databases are created? If so, MAXDOP could be set to 1 for the initial install and then it could be configured at the database level for operational purposes.  Is this a clever workaround or am I in bad idea territory?

Comment: It's not mentioned in official documentation. You can open up a PSS case to see if Microsoft will support it, but as of now, it's unsupported.

Comment: Confirmed with the PG, it is unsupported.